# getting null from realtime database in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a chat app in flutter using firebase , but i'm facing issues with getting data from realtime database , it is public chat , i'm not sure what is wrong that the data is not fetched , if anyone could help , i ll deeply appreciate it , thank you

- This is a screenshot from db

[image]

- This is how i'm getting data

```
Stream<Event> getMessages() {
   DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL: databaseUrl).reference().child('Messages');
   return  databaseReference.onValue;
 }
```

- This is my stream Builder

```
Expanded(child: Container(
        child: StreamBuilder<Event>(
          stream: AuthService().getMessages(),
          builder: (context,data){
            if(data.hasError){
              return Center(
                child: Text("No data 1"),
              );
            }
            if(data.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
              if(data.data!.snapshot.exists){
                print("data is in done" );
                Map<String,dynamic> values = data.data!.snapshot.value;
                for(var child in values.values){
                  var receiverName = child['userName'];
                  var receiverMessage = child['message'];
                  var receiverImageUrl = child['imageUrl'];
                  return Container(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 30,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(receiverImageUrl),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(receiverName),
                                Text(receiverMessage)
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              }
            }
            return Center(
              child: Text("No data 2"),
            );
          },
        ),
      )),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems in your code.

First up you're reading the entire database, only to use the `Messages` node. I recommend updating that to:

```
Stream<Event?> getMessages() {
  DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL: databaseUrl).reference().child('Messages');
  return  databaseReference.onValue;
}
```

Second, since you're reading `Messages` your `data.data!.snapshot` will have multiple messages. So calls like `data.data!.snapshot.value['userName']` won't work, because you don't say what message to read the `userName` from.

You'll want to loop through `data.data!.snapshot.value.values` to then get `['userName']` on the specific child snapshot it.

Comment: i have added some code for loop , i will update it again and please tell me if it is correct or not

Comment: I have updated the code regarding the node and loop , can you please check the code again , thank you

Comment: That update looks reasonable, and looks like it should address the two issues I identified. Is there any other problem remaining?

Comment: thank you so much for your answer , the other thing is i have to make my map have dynamic , dynamic , for some reason when i write string,dynamic , it shows null , but when i write dynamic,dynmaic , it returns data

Comment: Hmmm, that is interesting. It really is supposed to be `Map<String, dynamic>` since keys in Firebase Realtime Database can only be `String`. I wonder if that's a mistake in the library, or if something else is going on.

Comment: this is the error i get when it is string,dynamic ( type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')

Comment: this way it works for me Map<dynamic,dynamic> values = data.data!.snapshot.value;